# AngularJS adding and pushing in nested JSON objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, push

I have a JSON Object like this :

```
{
    "Name": "Shivansh",
    "RollNo": "1",
    "Stream": "CSE",
    "OverallScore": "76",
    "Semester": [
        {
            "SemesterName": "FY-2012 - 1",
            "TotalScore": "78.00",
            "StartDate" : "2012-02-14",
            "EndDate" : "2012-07-16",
            "Amount" : "55000",
            "Subject": [
                {
                    "subjectname": "maths",
                    "score": "81"
                },
                {
                    "subjectname": "chemistry",
                    "score": "79"
                },
                {
                    "subjectname": "physics",
                    "score": "77"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "SemesterName": "FY-2013-1",
            "TotalScore": "76.00",
            "StartDate" : "2013-02-16",
            "EndDate" : "2014-07-16",
            "Amount" : "55000",
            "Subject": [
                {
                    "subjectname": "ADA",
                    "score": "80"
                },
                {
                    "subjectname": "Operating System",
                    "score": "77"
                },
                {
                    "subjectname": "Databases",
                    "score": "73"
                },
                {
                    "subjectname": "Economics",
                    "score": "71"
                }
            ]
        }                
    ]
}
```

Now i want to add another semester field into this JSON by using `angularJS`. Can anyone help me how to achieve this. The next field that I would add may look like:

```
{
                    "SemesterName": "FY-2013-2",
                    "TotalScore": "75.00",
                    "StartDate" : "2011-02-16",
                    "EndDate" : "2012-07-16",
                    "Amount" : "55067800",
                    "Subject": [
                        {
                            "subjectname": "Sets and Probability",
                            "score": "78"
                        },
                        {
                            "subjectname": "Networking and Security",
                            "score": "76"
                        },
                        {
                            "subjectname": "Advanced DataBases",
                            "score": "72"
                        },
                        {
                            "subjectname": "Economics-2",
                            "score": "70"
                        }
                    ]
                }
```

so far I am using this type of controllers as mentioned below:

```
$scope.addRowSubject = function() {
            $scope.insertsub = {
                //id = $scope.getSubject.length+1;
                subjectname : '1',
                score : '1'
            };

            $scope.getSubject.push($scope.insertsub);
};
```

`getSubject` is the list of subjects which are present in one semester field. I am able to get this list without any issues.

```
$scope.addRowSemester = function() {
            $scope.insertsem = {
                //id = $scope.getSemester.length+1;
                StartDate : "1",
                EndDate : "1",
                Amount : "1",
                SemesterName : "1",
                TotalScore : "1",
                Subject : ""
            }
$scope.getSemester.push($scope.insertsem);
};
```

`getSemester` is the list of Semesters in a Student.

I am able to push a semester field inside my JSON but as the Subject field is `null` i am not able to push the subject field. I hope you are getting the idea.
So any suggestions about this..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you add a  plunkr?

Answer (score 1):

Subject properties of your jsonObject is should be an instance of array, like this:

```
$scope.addRowSemester = function() {
            $scope.insertsem = {
                //id = $scope.getSemester.length+1;
                StartDate : "1",
                EndDate : "1",
                Amount : "1",
                SemesterName : "1",
                TotalScore : "1",
                Subject : []
            }
```